# How to use awk to sort lines by length?

Tags: sorting, awk

I have the following Python script that I use to sort lines by length:

```
import fileinput
print "".join(sorted(fileinput.input(), key=len))
```

How do I write the same script in Awk?

Comment: Do you want a pure `awk` solution, or is a one-liner for use in the *NIX command shell the end goal? Most uses of `awk` tend to be one-liners that use line oriented input and output, which sorting violates; `awk` can do sorting, but most of the time you'd let the `sort` utility do the work, then process the result with `awk`. Also, which flavor of `awk`? [`gawk` provides `asort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html#Array-Sorting-Functions), but according to those docs, the function is non-standard; other versions require writing sort from scratch.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Wow I didn't think about all the intricacies. It'd be nice to have a one-liner but not required.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of of solutions using `awk` and `sort`:

```
# keep spaces
awk 'OFS = "\t" { print length, $0 }' file | sort -g | cut -f2-

# stripping out spaces from line before counting
awk 'OFS = "\t" { gsub (" ", "", $0); print length, $0 }' file | sort -g | cut -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk with sort is almost surely better than the following solution, which however does only use GNU awk, and illustrates the use of a user-defined comparator:

```
gawk '
  function clength(i1, v1, i2, v2) { return length(v1) - length(v2); }
  {a[++i] = $0;} 
  END { asort(a, aclone, "clength");
    for (i=1;i<=length(a);i++) { print aclone[i] }
  }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk (due to the function `asorti`):

```
awk '{O[NR]=$0;L[length*1000+NR]=NR}END{asorti(L,S);for(s in S)print O[L[S[s]]]}' fileinput
```

- I assume here that there is no more than 1000 lines (if more, just raise the `1000` to a number higher of the line count)
- because lines are loaded in memory, the shell `sort` is a better option on huge file even if it's create a new forked subshell.

I take the suggestion of @fedorqui to use NR as index in array instead of dedicated variable

Comment: Good one! Note you can also rely on the line number and say `O[NR]=$0`.